# Correct annotation to set primary key in Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Adding an event to my `dbContext` I can see that the table created by EF does not have the primary key I thought. I thought Entity Framework would use the member called `[class name]Id` as primary key. In the `Event` class this would be `EventId`. But all the entries in this column is receiving the id 0.

Is this how Entity Framework works cause I was expecting each `EventId` to be unique and set to primary key. Instead `LocationId` is set to primary key and foreign key. The class has the `LocationId` annotation `Key` and `Foreign Key`. This is because the tutorial I am following. For me it would make sense to have Location annotated with foreign key and `EventId` with `Key`.

[image]

Here is my `Event` class:

```
public class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        _sessions = new List<Session>();
    }

    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Location") ]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    ICollection<Session> _sessions;

    public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions {
        get { return _sessions; }
        set { _sessions = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove key in [Key, ForeignKey("Location") ] from LocationId and Add [Key ] over EventId

Answer (score 0):

remove key from LocationId and do this

```
[ForeignKey("Location")]
public int LocationId { get; set; }
```

and Add [Key] over EventId like this

```
[Key]
public int EventId { get; set; }
```

for more detail see this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Ive already tried this. Here is the modified class. 
http://pastebin.com/NSdY5fry

I get this error:
  Message=One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Event_Location_Source' in relationship 'Event_Location'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: you have to first drop the table and then recreate the table using Migrations then it will work

Comment: I didnt use migrations but erased the whole db. It was recreated. But I'll try with migrations.